# Why does ng-model set value of an input when there is ng-init?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular ( always working with jquery )

As I understand the `ng-model` directive binds the value of an input to an application data ; and the `ng-init` directive initializes an app data. So if I understand then the `ng-model` does not set the value of an input but stores the input value into the app data. Here is a snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John'">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" /></p>
<p>You wrote: {{ firstName }}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

At runtime the input has already a value set as John ! So why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've understood about both are correct. In this case you are setting the value of **`$scope`** variable **`firstName`** which binds to the input as **`John`**

When you set the value of $scope variable which binds to the input it gets binded to the input. So you see the output as John which is the value of $scope.firstName.

Comment: I still dont understand : why does `ng-model` sets the value of the input to be the scope variable ?

Comment: here ng-model is not setting the value to the scope variable. ng-init sets the value. since you are using the same variable in the input it is getting rendered

Comment: you said "it is getting rendered" : so does `ng-model` have other capabilities other than binding input value to app data ?

Comment: thank you very much for the link ; it mentions `ng-model is intended to be put inside of form elements and has two-way data binding ($scope --> view and view --> $scope)`

Answer (score 3):

**ng-init** directive is basically used for initializing a variable (*such initialization can also be done through controller*)

As you are intializing the scope variable firstName ='John'

**ng-model** is using the same scope variable to bind that value in the input

Apart from such initialization using **ng-init**, this directive is used for evaluating an expression in the current scope.